# Angular 4/5 value not updating

Tags: angular, angular5

I need some help. So I have function `selectedUser()` set `(onclick)` in my html, and when I click on any user in the list it takes it's id and stores it in the `selecedUserID`. And that is fine. But when I click on it I can see it on screen with {{ selectedUserID }} and in console, but it doesn't change the showed user here `this.selectedUser = json[this.selectedUserID]`, where selectedUserID is that ID I see change on the screen.

So the problem is that it is not updating when I click it, and I need your help to fix that.

**Component**

```
users;
result;
selectedUserID:number = 3;
selectedUser;

constructor() {

//show all people
this.users = json;

this.selectedUser= json[this.selectedUserID];

// show selected user
this.result = this.users.filter(user => this.selectedUser.friends.includes(user.id));
};


selectedUser(id) {
  this.selectedUserID = id;
  console.log(this.selectedUserID)
}
```

Comment: `this.selectedUser` is only set in the constructor.  Are you updating it anywhere else?

Comment: You mean selectedUserID?  I used selectedUserID to store id of that user after I click on it. And I want to use that ID number to pass it to json[' that id' ], so it looks like this json[5], or json[7], depening of what that ID is.

Comment: `this.selectedUser= json[this.selectedUserID];` This line is only run once when the component is created.  if you want it to run again when they click, you need to add it to your click handler

Comment: Yeah, it works! Thanks! I am so stupid :) You want to put that in answers so I can mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to change your `selectedUser` property to a getter like this:

```
get selectedUser() {
  return json[this.selectedUserID];
}
```